# How to browse for file (Win7/64bits)

Tags: windows, vbscript, hta

I need to quickly write a simple GUI over a command line application. Two steps are required:

1. Specify an input file path,
2. Specify an output file path (non existing)

I found out a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/272795/136285), however trying to get the above (1) to work seems like an insane task.

Indeed [BrowseForFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774065%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) seems to only work in some weird cases, you can use `BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEFILES` for only `*.pdf` and/or `*.txt` (trial and errors). I can get an error if I select a `*.dll` and/or a `*.jpg` (don't ask).

So instead, I gave up this approach and followed [another one](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_ui_fileopen.php), in this case (`objIE.Document.all.FileSelect`), only the **name** of the selected file is returned the path seems to be always set to `"c:/fakepath"` for some reason. So again I am missing the full path to be able to pass that to the command line app.

Is there any sane way (<10 lines of codes) to get (1) and (2) working on Win7/64bits (VBS, HTA...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if people are still interested in the BrowseForFolder file selection issue, but here's what I've found.
I had the same issue selecting files with BrowseForFolder using &H4000 / BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEFILES. I could get a return with .docx but not .doc files and as you say .pdf files.
For me .txt wouldn't return anything, as didn't WMI Backup .rec files that I needed for a script I'm writing, resulting in this error information:-

```
Error: Unspecified error
Code: 80004005
Source: (null)
```

After looking at other solutions I came back to this one as my preferred choice, plus it was doing my head in that it didn't want to work. So at the bitter end it seems to be this easy.
To get my .rec files recognized I add this to the registry:-

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.rec]
@="WMI.Backup"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMI.Backup]
@="WMI Backup"
"BrowseInPlace"="1"
```

To get .txt files recognized I add this to the registry:-

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile]
"BrowseInPlace"="1"
```

So "BrowseInPlace"="1" seems to be the nugget.

Seems so unbelievably easy that I'm sure this solution is out there somewhere but I never came across it so thought I'd put it online.

I would be interested to find that it works for others as I fear that this issue may of sent me mad, still can't believe it seems to work.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you need opening just **one file at a time** you can use the old fashion html tag
 in IE9 compatibility mode: in this mode the input will return the full path of the single selected file. But the caveats are that you cannot use multiple attribute or filter for file types with the accept attribute.

If you want to use the accept and the multiple attributes you have to set IE=10 compatibility mode into the meta tag content attribute so you can use one of these combinations:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9"/>
<input type="file"/>
```

You have hta features working but you cannot have accept and multiple attribute working for the input type="file"

or

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10"/>
<input type="file" accept="*.txt,*.doc" multiple />
```

in this case viceversa at the cost of losing some hta features.

Of course you have to put the meta tag into the head of the hta and the input tag into the body.

Also there are some workarounds as for instance using two different hta files:

- the main is set as  and deals with the HTA:APPLICATION... tag and into its body loads into an iframe an
- inner hta file with  that deals with the  and all the vbs code and all the rest of the content.
  In this case you really have two files each one loads its own part of your hta app.

But afaIk it is not easy to have into a single file working all together in harmony

- vbs
- input type file with accept and multiple attributes
- HTA:APPLICATION... tag
- and more

without having to edit the Win register or without using 3rd part dlls or other workarounds: so it seams there is not a direct and clean way to do this easily.

Answer (score -1):

Here are 3 different ways to do what you want:

```
http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_ui_fileopen.php
```